# How to test GeoIP on an internal network?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, tcp, geoip

I've got an application in which I am integrating GeoIP detection/lookup.  However, I am not sure how to go about testing the API considering that my test server is only located on my internal network (ie: not accessible from the internet).

The application is hosted in a JBoss 4.2.1 server, and my application is using the GeoIP to augment the access log information (tagging the IP with Geo data as well).

My first instinct would be to spoof my outgoing IP address, but if I do that, then the 3-way TCP handshake won't complete, and I wouldn't even receive an HTTP packet.

Is there any way to test GeoIP without using external proxies to reroute the traffic?  Are there tools out there that can help with kind of testing?  What would be a valid approach?  Should I concentrate more on writing some kind of filter to override/mock the source IP instead at the application level?

Comment: just set some random IP in your code. isntead of `getlocation(request.ip)`, do `getlocation('x.x.x.x')`. yes, it's hardcoded, but you'll get a location for that ip, not the actual internal ip.

Comment: @MarcB Sure - we've done that for dev purposes, but the QA department can never sign off on something like that, so I was looking for some other idea that I could leverage.